# JPAContainerFactory does not create the database table

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, vaadin, vaadin7, jpacontainer

I expected JPAContainer to create a database table automatically when 'hbm2ddl.auto' is set to 'update', however this seems to not be the case. Is there something wrong in my configuration or should i use something else to get the desired functionality?

I am using the following command to create a JPAContainer

```
accounts = JPAContainerFactory.make(Account.class, RumUI.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
```

The Accounts class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")    
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 24)
    @Column(name = "name", unique=true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 24)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Account() {
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

And the persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="RuM">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>ee.ut.cs.rum.domain.Account</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/RuM"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I would expect that the database table 'accounts' would be created automatically since 'hbm2ddl.auto' is set to 'update'. However the table is not created.

If i create Hibernate ServiceRegistry and SessionFactory directly using the same settings (using a Configuration object), then the table is created.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

@Entity
@Table(name="t_accounts)
public class Accout……

Comment: The entity annotation was missing from my question, but was present in the actual source. Otherwise ServiceRegistry and SessionFactory would also not have worked. But thank you for noticing. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: How do you solve the question? l want to learn this.Thank you !

Comment: Users can upvote or downvote the proposed solutions. The user who asked the question can select one of the solutions as the accepted one.

Comment: can you show your applicationContext.xml .`accounts = JPAContainerFactory.make(Account.class, RumUI.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);` l never use this in my jpa project. I want to  know ,why you need this.

Comment: I believe that vaadin has applicationcontext.xml file. It least i do not seem to have one in my project. My project is based on the default Vaadin project.

Comment: Can you tell me what frame  are you use in your project?

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
you can try this provider

Comment: Tried it and 'hbm2ddl.auto' == 'update' setting is still ignored. I feel that it is Vaadin's JPAContainer specific